# How to pad two strings on the same line in a checkedListBox C#?

Tags: c#

I have multiple strings that look like this: `"MyApp.exe"` and others like this: `"0x1234567A"`.

The dimensions vary, of course.

I want to arrange them on a single line in a `checkedListBox`.

I use the following code:

```
processes_checkedListBox.Items.Add(element[1] + element[2], false);
```

`element[1]` having `"MyApp.exe"` and `element[2]` `"0x1234567A"`.

So if I apply that code the result is something like this, obviously:

```
MyApp.exe0x1234567A
MyOtherApp.exe0x1234567B
```

I tried with this:

```
processes_checkedListBox.Items.Add(element[1] + element[2].PadLeft(5,' '), false);
```

The result on this case looks like this:

```
MyApp.exe     0x1234567A
MyOtherApp.exe     0x1234567B
```

If I apply the padding to the left, the result is identical with the first one.
Likewise if I apply padding to the right on the first element.
The font is the default checkedListBox one, nothing changed,
The padding is 40 spaces, I've inserted above 5 just as an example.

The desired result should be of course:

```
MyApp.exe        0x1234567A
MyOtherApp.exe   0x1234567B
```

I don't know how to do it, any suggestions, please?
(.NET 4.5 Framework and MVS 2015 - Windows Form Application)

**LATER EDIT**

```
private void Display_Processes_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        processes_checkedListBox.Items.Clear();

        string test = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
        string[] testArray = test.Split('\n');

        for (int i = 3; i < testArray.Length-1; ++i)
        {
            string[] element = testArray[i].Split('|');
            element[1] = element[1].Trim();
            element[2] = element[2].Trim();

            processes_checkedListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-20} {1,-20}",element[1] , element[2]), false);
        }
    }
```

This is my actual code, I am reading the info from a file that contains:

```
+----------------------------------------+-----------+
|             Process Name               | PID       |
+----------------------------------------+-----------+
| securityAccessModule.exe               | 0x127F003A|
| CMD.EXE                                | 0x77430012|
| ps.exe                                 | 0x77010062|
+----------------------------------------+-----------+
```

I still can't make it work, although I've tried your solutions. I see that in console it works fine. :(

Comment: you could pad with `\t`(tab) you could vary how many times u tab and see what fits best

Comment: I've updated the post. Thank you!

Comment: That code will just get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception

Comment: You were right, sorry. I've removed some data when I've provided you the information sample and I've messed up the index. Now it is ok, for (int i = 3; i < testArray.Length-1; ++i). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to have a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font).

Try the following code:

```
var txt = @"+----------------------------------------+-----------+
            |             Process Name               | PID       |
            +----------------------------------------+-----------+
            | securityAccessModule.exe               | 0x127F003A|
            | CMD.EXE                                | 0x77430012|
            | ps.exe                                 | 0x77010062|
            +----------------------------------------+-----------+";

processes_checkedListBox.Font = new Font(new FontFamily("Consolas"), processes_checkedListBox.Font.Size);
processes_checkedListBox.Items.Clear();

string test = txt;
var testArray = test.Split('\n');

for (int i = 3; i < testArray.Length - 1; ++i)
{
    string[] element = testArray[i].Split('|');
    element[1] = element[1].Trim();
    element[2] = element[2].Trim();

    processes_checkedListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-25} {1,-25}", element[1], element[2]), false);
}
```

This shows as follows:

[image]

Comment: Never considered to change the Font.
Consolas did the job, thank you Kevin!

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0,-20}{1}", element[1], element[2]);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you please explain this to me a bit? If i put it into my code, there will be lines with lot of spaces, others with the strings glued together.

Comment: @bvg You can define the width of the string that is inserted into the result string by using syntax such as {0,12}, which inserts a 12-character string. In this case, the string representation of the first object is right-aligned in the 12-character field. By default, strings are right-aligned within their field if you specify a field width. To left-align strings in a field, you preface the field width with a negative sign, such as {0,-12} to define a 12-character right-aligned field.

Comment: Much clearer now. I appreciate your help, melya! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the results to have the same total length with not less than 5 space in between, but the closer to 5 spaces, the better. Due to this fact, you will need to find the maximum total length of app name and hexa. Let's suppose it is n. In this case, the length of all texts will be n + 5. For each pair, calculate the difference between n + 5 and the sum of the length of the file name and hexa. The result will be the amount of space you will need to put between left and right.

Comment: I've already tried this also. My maximum app length is 24 + 5 spaces, 29.
I've put a while loop and till element.Length is not 29 I concatenate " " to the string. But it would still won't work because I think it is something about the width of the letters, "www" has not the same dimension as "lll" and there will be still some problems.

Comment: @bvg in that case you need to measure the with of each character, including space and use the sum of the width of the characters in your measurement.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know that I could actually do this. I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thank you, Lajos!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with string formatting:

```
    var items1 = new []{"MyApp.exe", "0x1234567A" };
    var items2 = new []{"MyAwesomeApp.exe", "0x1234567B"};
    var items3 = new []{ "MyApp3.exe",  "0x1234567C"};

    Console.WriteLine(string.format("{0,-20} {1,-20}", items1));
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20}", items2);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20}", items3);
```

This will give you

```
MyApp.exe            0x1234567A          
MyAwesomeApp.exe     0x1234567B          
MyApp3.exe           0x1234567C
```

Comment: Could you please try it on a checkBoxList? I saw that on the Console it works, but on my WFA it does not. Maybe it's something related.

Comment: I've added another answer to answer the second bit

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using `PadRight`

```
string s1= "MyApp.exe";
string s2= "0x1234567A";
string s3= "MyOtherApp.exe";
string s4= "0x1234567B";

Console.WriteLine(s1.PadRight(20,' ') + s2);
Console.WriteLine(s3.PadRight(20,' ') + s4);

//melya's answer
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-20}{1}", s1, s2));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-20}{1}", s3, s4));
```

Output: Both will lead to same output:

```
 MyApp.exe           0x1234567A
 MyOtherApp.exe      0x1234567B
```

Check it on [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gHHBng)

@melya's answer is also good.!

Comment: I see that on Console it works fine, but I also think that it has something to do with my checkedListBox, I work on a WFA. There those solution aren't good. Thank you!

Comment: too bad. I'm not using PC to test it now, hopefully by the time I get to test it on PC u may find the answer

Answer (score 0):

Firs you need find element from index =0 with maximum length. Maximum length is for this MyOtherApp.exe and it has 14 characters. Let say

```
var lngth = 14;
```

Then you need to do PadRight (put + 1 to have one space extra) on the first element to all list items:

```
 processes_checkedListBox.Items.Add(element[1].PadRight(lngth+1,' ') + element[2], false);
```

PadRight = 5 do nothing becouse it is total length of the string which will be more than 5 in this example.

Comment: You are right, with 5 is redundant, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Tab** `\t`:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>();

        entries.Add(new Entry()
        {
            App = "MyApp.exe",
            Value = "0x1234567A"
        });

        entries.Add(new Entry()
        {
            App = "MyOtherApp.exe",
            Value = "0x1234567B"
        });

        foreach (Entry entry in entries)
        {
            //append multiple tabs here - the longer your appname is.
            builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", entry.App, entry.Value));
        }
        Console.Write(builder.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Entry
{
    public string App { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
MyApp.exe       0x1234567A
MyOtherApp.exe  0x1234567B
```

Comment: I've updated the post with my actual code.
In Console it works, indeed.